# Problems with page layout after migrating to JSF 2.0, RichFaces 4.1.0 Final

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have updated my project to richfaces 4.1.0 and JSF 2.0. I have abviously changed the maven dependencies, updated web.xml, faces-config.xml, swtiched from *.jsp files to *.xhtml files, updated all head,body,form to h:head, h:body, h:form. However, I have significant problems with my page layout and a4j:ajax behavior. I think that it's best if I just list the problems:

- My rich:datatable skin stopped working. I even tried deleting the columnClass etc. attributes from the  tag to leave it with default bluesky skin, but the outcome looks just like a plain html table (no lines, no background, no colors).
- the a4j:axjax tag works much worse thatn a4j:support did. For my selectOneMenus I tried event="change" but it doesn't work. Only after adding a valueChangedListener to the  tags and tried event="valueChange" it worked.
- rich:calendar elements are not 'clickable' - when I move the coursor over the button to popup the calendar it's not changing and when I click on the button nothing happens. I also need the a4j:ajax here but am not able to test it.
- Although event="valueChange" worked on selectOneMenu, my a4j:mediaOutput image is not re-rendered. And the chart was the reason why I switched to JSF 2.0 because I needed to use the session-data-helper mechanism to load the images. Is there a special mechanism to rerender (or now 'render' with a4j:ajax) this element when it's using the session-data-helper for loading data?

Here are the web.xml and index.xhtml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" 
version="2.5">
  <display-name>presentation graph</display-name>

    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/data-helper.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
      <param-name>javac.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:sdh="http://richfaces.org/session-data-helper"> 


<h:head>

         <title>Graph presentation</title>

    <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
        <h:form id="form">

        <div class="grid_2">
            <rich:calendar value="#{formBean.date}"
                            id="date" popup="true" datePattern="yyyy/MM/dd"
                            showApplyButton="false" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px"> 
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="resultTable chart" execute="@this" listener="#{formBean.dateSelected}"/>           
            </rich:calendar>
        </div>

        <div class="grid_2">
         <h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{formBean.model.selected_id}" valueChangeListener="#{formBean.selected}" styleClass="comboBoxes">
            <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.myModelValues}" />
            <a4j:ajax  execute="@this" event="valueChange"  render="resultTable chart"  ajaxSingle="true"/>
         </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div> 

        <div id="list" class="container2">
        <rich:dataTable id="resultTable" value="#{formBean.results}" var="query" rows="10" headerClass="columnclass" rowClasses="rowclass" styleClass="datatable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" rules="rows" >

               <rich:column headerClass="columnclass"  width="100" >
                    <f:facet name="header"> 
                        <h:outputText value="Values" style="align:center; text-align:center; " />
                    </f:facet>
                  <h:outputText value="#{query.val}" />
               </rich:column>            
               <rich:column headerClass="columnclass"  width="100" >
                    <f:facet name="header"> 
                        <h:outputText value="Models" style="align:center; text-align:center; " />
                    </f:facet>
                  <h:outputText value="#{query.model}" />
               </rich:column>    
               <f:facet name="footer">
                   <rich:dataScroller page="#{formBean.page}" style="margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 15%; width: 70%;">
                          <f:facet name="first">
                                    <h:outputText value="First" />
                          </f:facet>
                          <f:facet name="last">
                                    <h:outputText value="Last" />
                          </f:facet>
                    </rich:dataScroller>
                </f:facet>
            </rich:dataTable>
      </div>

      <div id="graph" class="container2">
                    <a4j:mediaOutput 
                         id="chart"
                         element="img"
                         cacheable="false"
                         session="true"
                         createContent="#{mediaPainter.drawChartImage}"
                         value = "#{sdh:storeData(formBean.chartData)}"
                         mimeType="image/jpeg" 
                         />       
      </div>   
           </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

here is a list of .jar files deployed with the webapp:

cssparser-0.9.5.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar
ehcache-1.6.0.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
guava-r08.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar
javax.faces-2.1.3.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
jcommon-1.0.16.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.1.0.Final.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
sac-1.3.jar
jstl-api-1.2.jar

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.models.presentation.</groupId>
    <artifactId>graph_presentation</artifactId>
    <name>graph_presentation</name>
    <version>Final</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <url>http://jboss.org/richfaces</url>

    <repositories>
        <!-- You should seriously consider using a repository manager or declare repositories in your settings.xml.
           See http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/   -->
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- Setting this property using archetype-metadata.xml requiredPorperty
             so that generated project uses correct version of richfaces.
         -->
        <org.richfaces.bom.version>4.1.0.Final</org.richfaces.bom.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>individuel_broadcast3</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jee6</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-jee6</webappDirectory>
                            <classifier>jee6</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>jee6</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>war</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-jee6</webappDirectory>
                                    <classifier>jee6</classifier>
                                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces*</packagingExcludes>
                                    <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces*</warSourceExcludes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Open the webbrowser developer toolset (press F12 in Firebug/Chrome/IE9) and check the network traffic. Are all JS/CSS resources are successfully downloaded or not? If not, why not? Is the URL wrong or been restricted by some `Filter` which is also mapped on JSF requests?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine there. The css are not the problem because I ried the page without any css classes or tags (deleted all <div> tags, and deleted all styleClass attributes from other tags) and it did not help. I have edit the first post adding the list of .jar files deployed with the webapp - maybe sth is missing there?

Comment: Ok I used chrome with the console and I saw there are some errors thrown. I have edit the first post with them.

Comment: So, the necessary scripts are just *not* included in the generated HTML `<head>` at all? (you said that you didn't see errors in network traffic)

Comment: Yes the firefox tool I used reported nothing, only the chrome one find the errors. However I was able to eliminate them when I started the project from scratch, generating the whole structure with mvn archetype:generate tool. Now the errors don't appear and I am able to click on the calendar button. However the calendar is also missing the skin, like the datatable - plain transparent text appears... The rest of the problems remains the same.

Comment: So, you're using Maven to manage dependencies? I wouldn't be surprised if something failed in that area. E.g. incorrect repo or dependency.

Comment: Yes I am using maven as it's actually mentioned at the beginning. Using the chrome tool I have seen that the page is loaded with my css files and only skinning.css file which does not have the classes for datatable or calendar. Shouldn't there be more files?Can this be related to the issues with a4j:ajax failing mechanism? I also added the pom.xml to the 1st post.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was in the container cause the same project worked on another Tomcat instance, which didn't had the previous JSF 1.2 version deployed.